# Node.js executing window.postmessage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working with two sites and use window.postMessage API to communicate between the two.

Is it possible to use the postMessage API with node.js? As I would eventually like to take any essential javascript communication over to the server side to allow more stability. (i.e. not rely on users having a modern browser).

Also are there any good examples of this?

I have checked google nothing obvious jumps out at me...

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not directly.

`postMessage` is used to communicate between two pages in the browser but Node.JS (in this context) runs on the server.

You could have a page use Ajax to communicate with Node.JS and then `postMessage` to communicate with another page … but in most cases you might as well have the other page communicate using Ajax directly (using CORS to grant permission).

Comment: Cool, that's what it looked like to me, I just needed a confirmation. Thanks